# Sphere Online Judge, Problem 2: Prime Number Generator

Tags: java, optimization, primes

I am trying to solve [this](http://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIME1/) problem on Sphere Online Judge. I keep getting a timeout error. Any comments or suggestions are welcome and appreciated.

```
package info.danforbes.sphere;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException;
import java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class PrimeNumberGenerator {
  private static BufferedReader inStream;
  private static BufferedWriter outStream;
  private static List<Entry<Integer, Integer>> pairs = new ArrayList<Entry<Integer, Integer>>();
  private static HashSet<Integer> primes = new HashSet<Integer>();

  private static void getPairs(int numCases) throws MalformedInputException {
    String line;
    int spaceNdx;
    int num1, num2;
    try {
      for (int pairNdx = 0; pairNdx < numCases; ++pairNdx) {
        line = inStream.readLine();
        spaceNdx = line.indexOf(' ');
        num1 = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, spaceNdx));
        num2 = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(spaceNdx + 1));
        if (num1 < 1) throw new MalformedInputException(num1);
        if (num1 > num2) throw new MalformedInputException(num2 - num1);
        if (num2 > 1000000000) throw new MalformedInputException(num2);
        if (num2 - num1 > 100000) throw new MalformedInputException(num2 - num1);
        pairs.add(new SimpleEntry<Integer, Integer>(num1, num2));
      }
      inStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("IOException encounterd!");
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(-1);
    }
  }

  private static boolean isPrime(int num) {
    boolean isPrime = true;
    if (num < 2) isPrime = false;
    else if (num > 3) {
      if (num % 2 == 0 || num % 3 == 0) isPrime = false;
      else if (!primes.contains(num)){
        int sqrRoot = (int)Math.sqrt(num);
        for (int factorNdx = 1; 6 * factorNdx - 1 <= sqrRoot; ++factorNdx) {
          if (num % (6 * factorNdx + 1) == 0 || num % (6 * factorNdx - 1) == 0) {
            isPrime = false;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    if (isPrime) primes.add(num);
    return isPrime;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length == 0) {
      inStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      outStream = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
    }

    StringBuilder resultBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    try {
      if (inStream == null && outStream == null) {
        inStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
        outStream = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(args[1]));
      }

      int numCases = Integer.parseInt(inStream.readLine());
      if (numCases > 10) throw new MalformedInputException(numCases);
      getPairs(numCases);
      int beg, end;
      for (Entry<Integer, Integer> anEntry : pairs) {
        beg = anEntry.getKey();
        end = anEntry.getValue();
        for (int rangeNdx = beg; rangeNdx <= end; ++rangeNdx) {
          if (isPrime(rangeNdx)) resultBuilder.append(Integer.toString(rangeNdx) + "\n");
        }

        resultBuilder.append("\n");
      }

      resultBuilder.delete(resultBuilder.length() - 2, resultBuilder.length());
      outStream.write(resultBuilder.toString());
      outStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("IOException encountered!");
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(-1);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll make general statements not addressing (or not limited to) performance.

---

Your overall design is not very Object-Oriented. Usage of static/global variables is discouraged for a reason, it is very hard to follow the flow the program. Consider rewriting it with proper classes/encapsulation.

You could extract reading into one function, which then returns the list of pairs which another function can work on. Some pseudo code:

```
main()
    List pairs
    if args provided
        pairs = pairsFromFile(args[0])
    else
        pairs = pairsFromStdIn()

    foreach pair in pairs
        processpair(pair)
```

---

Your usage of one-line `if`s is partly confusing, consider to expand those to at least two lines for readability:

```
if(test)
    return true;
```

---

You're declaring and actively throwing exceptions which never get caught, that means that your application will exit with a thrown exception, that's a bad thing. Applications should handle exceptions at least in the main loop and exit gracefully.

---

Consider writing directly to the output-stream instead of buffering everything in a StringBuilder. While it might hurt performance if you're doing *a lot* of writing, it will remove some of the complexity.

---

```
System.out.println("IOException encounterd!");
```

Exceptions and errors should traditionally go to `System.err`.

---

You're using `System.exit()` at some places, it might be more desirable to let the main loop handle the application flow instead of "exiting" from any or some functions. I also now realize that you're using some sort of template to handle exceptions (write to out, print stacktrace, exit(-1)), please don't just slap an "error-handling-template" on it and be done with it. Handle exceptions *in a context-sensitive way*.

---

`isPrime()` does use a temporary variable `isPrime` when returning at the appropriate places would be more then enough.

```
private static boolean isPrime(int num) {
  if (num < 2)
    return false;
  else if (num > 3) {
    // Loop here
        if (num % (6 * factorNdx + 1) == 0 || num % (6 * factorNdx - 1) == 0) {
          return false;
        }
  }

  if (isPrime) primes.add(num);
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, Bobby. Unfortunately, they didn't seem to have an impact on the performance of my code, and it's still failing Sphere with a timeout error.